# How to fetch the files from local windows Share in Talend

Tags: talend

How can I fetch a list of files from local Windows share (that requires credentials)? Is there anywhere I can specify a username/password to authenticate to that share location? using talend.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's an option for you because you didn't provide many context information.

But you could use the `tSystem` component to execute a command like this :

```
net use x: \\share\some /user:username password
```

Then use the `tFileList` component in order to retrieve the files from that directory.

Comment: Thanks, @Jean-Michel-Garcia. This trick worked for me, the only point I see is when your password expires, so I defined a job parameter to pass it in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can mapped shared drive on your machine(where you want to execute the Talend job) then used that mapped drive location to get the files.